# How does Visual Studio detect WCF is needed

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I have a project that I used to load..... all was good and right with the world.

Then I pulled a new version.... Now I can't load the .csproj into Visual Studio...it claims because the WCF feature is needed....

I know that is it not installed by default, and I need to install it...that is NOT the question...

Rather what specific elements does Visual Studio look for in the .csproj file (or related) to make this determination...

I have searched the web, and tried various edits to the .csproj but have not yet been able to conslusively figure out *exactly* how visual studio is doing this.

Comment: This is a reference for installing wcf in the 2019 version: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/installing-wcf-in-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: REgarding above comment.... This is NOT about hw to install the component... Just how does visual studio detect the sutuation so that it fails to even load the .csproj until the component is added.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have a project with a specific GUID that indicates it is a WCF project.

This could either be the Project Type GUID (as specified in the .sln file) or via a `<ProjectTypeGuids>` property in the project file itself.

Newer dependencies upon VS workloads can be specified in a `.vsconfig` file, but given all you did was update VS I doubt that is the reason.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks.. I will look into that again, I have 3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699 as the known Project Type Guid for WCF... It does not appear to exist in the source tree at all...

Also I did not update Visual Studio... I have been working on a machine where it is not installed. Then I did a pull from Git (or a branch switch, dont remember) and now it can not load the one project and is giving WCF missing (never installed, don't want it installed) as the reason... So the goal is to revert back the specific change to .csproj or .sln or "other" that is triggering the blockage.